# A more reliable UDP server in .net by binding the port for listening?

Tags: .net, udp, winsock

I need to implement an UDP server to receive reports from a series of devices that can only use this protocol for reporting (I cannot change them). Historically I used C++ and Winsock to implement this kind of server (with a socket bound to the listening port and using recvfrom). This kind of implementation ensures that even if my program is not actually blocking on recvfrom(), a small number of packet is buffered waiting for it in the Winsock library, so fewer packets are lost. I could even attempt to tune the buffer size with WSAIoctl() if the underlying network driver supports it.

I'm trying to implement a .Net (Framework 4) service for this purpose, but all the examples I've found on the Internet use the UdpClient class, which is nice in a way but doesn't seem well suited for this task, as it allows for "holes" in the listening procedure. For example:

```
Dim server = New UdpClient(...)
Dim remote = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
...
Dim pkt1 = server.Receive()
... some processing A ...
Dim pkt2 = server.Receive(remote)
... some processing B ...
Dim pkt3 = server.Receive(remote)
```

The way the API is implemented in the UDPClient class, it seems to me that packets might be lost if they arrive during the "processing A" or "processing B" stages of the program, since no socket is actually bound to the listening address/port at that times and the OS should discard them. I could try to make "processing A" and "processing B" as quick as possible, but they will always be there.

I am fully aware that UDP is a connectionless / non-reliable protocol, which means that packets might get lost no matter what I do, but losing packets *after* they've reached the server only because the API has limitations feels pretty silly to me.

In order to ensure that no packet is missing (as long as it has reached the server), an object permanently bound to the listening port is needed. I were able do that in VB6 with the Winsock ActiveX control, as I can do with the binary Winsock API from C/C++, but I could not find a way to do this in .Net. Is there a way? Is my analysis correct or I'm missing some point?

Thanks in advance,

Guille.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No packet will be lost** unless you fill the network buffer by either sending such a large amount of data, or you take a long time before calling receive again. If you receive packets while doing something else they are buffered in the network buffer (that's what it is for) till you call receive again which will deliver one packet (datagram) up at a time in UDP.

(I am surprised it is not the same using Winsock directly!)

Typically peers using the synchronous Receive() method will have a loop like:

```
// Disclaimer: I don't know VB! 

While True
   Dim datagram = server.Receive()
   // do stuff
```

Comment: You are right. Somehow I thought that the bind was performed on the Receive call, but it is actually performed on object creation if you use Dim cl = New UdpClient(port), although documentation doesn't clarify that properly.